# Is this mysql query possible?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO example_table(`id`,`name`) VALUES (MAX(id)+1,`superman`) ;
```

The above query doesn't work, what could be the correct equivalent of this query ?
I want the id column to behave like autoincrement column, but I cannot have it as autoincrement for some reasons.

Comment: What is the problem that you cannot have it as autoincrement? It will be faster than any upcoming solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    example_table (id, name)
SELECT  MAX(id) + 1, 'superman'
FROM    example_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal you have to check the A_I check box, this is in the latest version of MySQL, if you have created the table, and after you want to activate auto increment it wouldn't be possible.

You can try

```
INSERT INTO second_table (fk, a, b, c) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1, 2, 3)
```

Success